# Open a class div on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am making this website, and I want it so when you click on a navigation link (hyperlink) it will show a div.

This is what I have:

http://pastebin.com/Lp2aWFPy

I'd really like to have just the classes.

Thanks guys!

Comment: For future questions, jsFiddle is more useful. http://jsfiddle.net/w3RzP/

Comment: Oh Okay, Thanks, I will do that from now on. Sorry if it looks messy :/

Comment: No problem, it's just an advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy to use *jQuery* and make your life easier, you can achieve the result expected like that:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="myLink" href="#">Services</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="alert-message notice">
    You are already here! <a class="myLink" href="#">Hide</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert-message {
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.alert-message.error {
    background-color: #ffe9e9;
    border-color: #e99f9f;
    color: #d25c5a;
}
.alert-message.error a {
    color: #d25c5a;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("a.myLink").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("div.alert-message").toggle();

        return false;
    });
});
```

Working link: http://jsfiddle.net/j9EBS/

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('divbox').style.display='block'">Click</a>

<div id="divbox" style="display:none">divbox</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/ogtys

Comment: This answer is incomplete. How to hide the box, as the question proposes? Also, and more important, the OP wants to rely on classes, not ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of using jQuery for this:

**jQuery**

```
$('.a_toggle').click(function() {

    $('.alert-message').toggle();

});

$('.a_hide').click(function() {

    $('.alert-message').hide();

});
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#" class="a_toggle">Services</a></li>

<div class="alert-message notice" style="display:none">You are already here! <a href="#" class="a_hide">Hide</a></div>
```

You can click on 'Services' to hide/close the menu, when you click on 'Hide', the menu will also close. If you don't have experience with jQuery, see [this](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w3RzP/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv()"></a>

<div id="content" style="display:none">
</div>
```

js function

```
function showDiv()
{
  document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
}
```

in your code you are trying to set the class as **head_alert**.But there is no class name called head_alert. Its an id. So you should try

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('alert-message').id = 'head_alert'; return false;" href="#">Services</a>
```

**Edited :** or else you can change your **#head_alert** to **.head_alert**

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('alert-message').className = 'head_alert'; return false;" href="#">Services</a>
```

Comment: The OP wants to rely on classes, not ids.

Comment: Edited accordingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

onclick of **service** alert-message div will be visible and then click on **hide** it will disappear.
Here is the code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function showDiv()
    {
      document.getElementById("alert-message").style.display = "block";
    }

      </script>

    <li><a onclick="document.getElementById('alert-message').style.display='block'" href="#">Services</a></li>

        <div id="alert-message" style="display:none;"> You are already here!
                                    <a onclick="document.getElementById('alert-message').style.display='none'; return false;" href="#">Hide</a>

                    </div>
```

You can also look for Jquery, but you require plain javascript right?